# How can we create in EMM 2.0.0 roles as default one in EMM1.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

IN EMM version 1.1.0, the default roles are :

- internal/store
- internal/publisher
- internal/reviewer
- admin

In EMM 2.0.0, there are only admin role.

How can we create roles same as 1.1.0 in 2.0.0?

Comment: No. I can see those roles in `Home>Identity> Users and Roles>List> Roles` except reviewer role.

Comment: I mean on the emm page and not in the carbone management page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the same roles with `PRIMARY` domain selected for domain drop down menu, using carbon management console. After that you should be able to access the required roles in emm user adding page. Don't forget to add the same permissions as before for the newly created roles.